# Sending push notification when user terminates/kill app react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, background

I have some features in my react native app that wont work if user terminates/kills the app.

I would like to inform the user that the app has reduced functionality by sending them a push notification if user kills the app.

Is there a way to do this in react native for android and iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via the React Native [AppState](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate).

If you also don't have push notifications integrated in your app, [heres](https://notifee.app/) the package I like to use.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried this, but it doesent work. I called 

"export const pushNotification = (title: string, message: string) => {
  PushNotification.localNotification({
    channelId: 'channel',
    title: title,
    message: message,
    id: '1',
  });
};" 

In App.tsx on "componentWillUnmount" and it does not trigger. 
However it got triggered when my application hot reloaded for some reason

Comment: Wow, it actually doesn't.  I just tried it out myself and I don't get why it wouldn't work its a cleanup function that gets called when the component unmount's and you usually use it to unsubscribe from listeners. Did you tried out the AppState?

Comment: As far as i know, the AppSate does not a have way to distingush when app is in background and when app is terminated/killed. I would not want to notify user everytime the app goes into the background. I just want to notify if the user actually kills the app.